# How to make initialCameraPosition from my address in flutter google maps?

Tags: android, flutter, location, google-maps-flutter

I tried to determine my address's camera position by using 'geolocator' library but I don't know how to set it into the google map's initial camera position

```
searchAndNavigate() {
      searchAddress = widget.author.address;
      Geolocator().placemarkFromAddress(searchAddress).then((result) {
        mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(
            target:
            LatLng(result[0].position.latitude, result[0].position.longitude),
            zoom: 10.0)));
      });
    }

    void onMapCreated(controller) {
      setState(() {
        mapController = controller;
      });
    }

    Widget mapSection = Container(
      height: 400,
      width: 400,
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
        child: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(40.7128, -74.0060), zoom: 10.0)),
      ),
    );

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      searchAndNavigate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I set initial camera position

```
//initialize _center
Position _center;
final Set<Marker> _markers = {};

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
//Then define _center in initState 
    _center = Position(locationData.latitude, locationData.longitude);

 _markers.add(
      Marker(
        // This marker id can be anything that uniquely identifies each marker.
        markerId: MarkerId(_center.toString()),
        position: _center,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: widget.hearingItem.location.locationName,
          snippet: widget.hearingItem.location.address,
        ),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      ),
    );
  }


 GoogleMap(
      myLocationEnabled: true,
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      markers: _markers,
      gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
        Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
          () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
        ),
      ].toSet(),
//Finally assign _center to target in CameraPosition
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: _center,
        zoom: 11.0,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I am very grateful to you, but can you add that code?

Comment: what more code would you like the code to get your initial position from geolocation

Comment: did this not answer your question

Answer (score 0):

If you have to implement that, you need to give it a custom location or display a loader while your app gets your current location. After the app gets your current location you have to call a camera update to move the view to your current location.

> You could give this a shot that should work perfectly.
>   Remember you don't have watch position. You can just get position and move the camera to that position after the position has been returned.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => HomeState();

}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  Location _location = Location();
  LocationData _locationData;

  watchLocation() async{

    _location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {

      LatLng latLng = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
      CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15);
      mapController.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

      setState(() {
        this._locationData = currentLocation;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    watchLocation();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          GoogleMap(
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            mapToolbarEnabled: true,
            zoomControlsEnabled: false,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: LatLng(this._locationData?.latitude ?? 6.7008168, this._locationData?.longitude ?? -1.6998494),
              zoom: 14.4746,
            ),
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              setState(() {
                mapController = controller;
              });
          ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```